# QtQuick Templates popup vs QtQuick Controls popup

Tags: qt, qt5, qtquick2, qt-quick, qtquickcontrols2

What is the difference between a Qt Quick Templates popup vs QtQuick Controls popup?

The popups I get from `import QtQuick.Templates 2.0` vs `import QtQuick.Controls 2.0` seem to have minor behavior differences.

[1] https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.8/qml-qtquick-controls2-popup.html

[2] http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-templates2-qmlmodule.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The templates are just the logical skeleton of the actual controls without the graphical parts, the popup from controls is just a decorated version of the popup from templates:

```
//Popup.qml
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Templates 2.0 as T

T.Popup {
    id: control

    implicitWidth: Math.max(background ? background.implicitWidth : 0,
                            contentWidth > 0 ? contentWidth + leftPadding + rightPadding : 0)
    implicitHeight: Math.max(background ? background.implicitHeight : 0,
                             contentWidth > 0 ? contentHeight + topPadding + bottomPadding : 0)

    contentWidth: contentItem.implicitWidth || (contentChildren.length === 1 ? contentChildren[0].implicitWidth : 0)
    contentHeight: contentItem.implicitHeight || (contentChildren.length === 1 ? contentChildren[0].implicitHeight : 0)

    padding: 12

    contentItem: Item { }

    background: Rectangle {
        border.color: "#353637"
    }
}
```

So there shouldn't really be any behavioral differences.